# Almost all queries have become slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel-4

So this one is puzzling me. 2 days ago, almost all queries on our server have become slow. The slow query log is practically modified each time a page is served.

What puzzles me is that we don't have a particularly large table, only 15,000 or so entries, and the indexes are (as best to my knowledge) aren't an issue. Also running the same queries in PHPMYADMIN is done in virtually zero time.

The table users has Id, Name, Country, AccID, crmstatus, modified_time, last_comment and calls.

The server has 8 cores and 16GB of RAM.

Here's our my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit = 1024000
query_cache_type = 1 
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 3
slow-query-log = 1
long_query_time = 0.5
query_cache_size=1G
join_buffer_size=16M
tmp_table_size=512M
max_heap_table_size=1G
thread_cache_size=8
table_open_cache=4096
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
key_buffer_size=256M
query_cache_limit=512M
tmp_table_size=512M
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
log_error = /var/log/mysqlerror.log
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

And here's the last few slow queries, which really shouldn't be.

```
# User@Host: REMOVED[REMOVED] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.352077  Lock_time: 0.000062 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1465820458;
update `users` set `modified_time` = '2016-06-13 12:20:57', `last_comment` = '2016-06-13 12:20:57' where `id` = '50045170';
# Time: 160613 14:21:28
# User@Host: REMOVED[REMOVED] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.613013  Lock_time: 0.000041 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1465820488;
update users set calls = calls+1, modified_time="2016-06-13 12:21:26" where id = '50045127';
# Time: 160613 14:21:47
# User@Host: REMOVED[REMOVED] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 9.126265  Lock_time: 0.000055 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1465820507;
update `users` set `modified_time` = '2016-06-13 12:21:38', `last_comment` = '2016-06-13 12:21:38' where `id` = '50037097';
# User@Host: REMOVED[REMOVED] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 9.051441  Lock_time: 0.000053 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1465820507;
update users set calls = calls+1, modified_time="2016-06-13 12:21:38" where id = '50045104';
# User@Host: REMOVED[REMOVED] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 6.198130  Lock_time: 0.000042 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1465820507;
update `users` set `modified_time` = '2016-06-13 12:21:41', `last_comment` = '2016-06-13 12:21:41' where `id` = '50015310';
# Time: 160613 14:22:03
# User@Host: REMOVED[REMOVED] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.770877  Lock_time: 0.000074 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1465820523;
update users set calls = calls+1, modified_time="2016-06-13 12:22:01" where id = '50045235';
# User@Host: REMOVED[REMOVED] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.564553  Lock_time: 0.000043 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1465820523;
update users set calls = calls+1, modified_time="2016-06-13 12:22:02" where id = '50045126';
# Time: 160613 14:22:29
# User@Host: REMOVED[REMOVED] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 11.289152  Lock_time: 0.000064 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1465820549;
update users set calls = calls+1, modified_time="2016-06-13 12:22:18" where id = '50045232';
# User@Host: REMOVED[REMOVED] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 11.016395  Lock_time: 0.000085 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1465820549;
update `users` set `crmstatus` = 'Decline', `modified_time` = '2016-06-13 12:22:18' where `id` = '50045055';
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do NOT refer to IDs as a string, i.e. use where id = 50045232 instead of where id = '50045232' - it's possible that it could be taking longer than it should because it's comparing strings not numbers (check the ID field is INT not VARCHAR too)

Comment: I don't write the SQL directly, but rather use the built in Laravel 4 functions. Here's how the query looks code-wise:

DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', $_POST['userid'])
    ->update(array('crmstatus' => $_POST['crmstatus'], 'modified_time' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s')));

Comment: Most of your queries look like ...... where `id` = '50045055'; Are you using a string (text) as primary key?

Comment: Primay key is bingint (ID). I'm using Laravel 4 see reply above.

Comment: MySQL has an `explain` function; append `explain ` to the front of a query, and it will tell you about what tables and indexes the query will use, etc. You could try using that to get a diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I get errors when I try to use explain though. 
Query: explain update users set last_action = "2016-06-13 14:04:12" where id = 5004;
Error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update users...

Comment: `explain` does not work against `update` prior to version 5.6.3

Comment: `INT = 'string'` works OK.  `VARCHAR = number` has multiple problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch!

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728  -- (should remove)
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
query_cache_type = 1    -- usually a waste on production servers
query_cache_size=1G     -- TERRIBLE!  Don't go over about 50M
tmp_table_size=512M     -- Dangerously high - suggest 100M
max_heap_table_size=1G  -- Dangerously high - suggest 100M
key_buffer_size=256M
tmp_table_size=512M  -- redundant
log_error = /var/log/mysqlerror.log   -- typo?
default-storage-engine=MyISAM   -- InnoDB is preferred
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` -- need to see Engine and index(es).

What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Can you provide us a link where these values are *explained* as you did it. Usually a *naive* optimizer would suppose more RAM is better performance...

Comment: [Memory allocation](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory); and [Various tips](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots).  More is not always better.